# Calculate a correction factor between two sets of data

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, regression

I'm a data science student and have a problem with harvesting data.There are two sets of geographic data (stored as points) that stores the yield of a soybeans harvest in the same field, they are from different harvesters. My purpose is to use these sets to generate a interpolated map of the yield across the field.
The problem is that one of these sets have the yield data stored with a different scale from the other due to not calibrating both harvesters. It's not possible to make a interpolated map with these two sets, since they have different scales, and that's exactly what I wish to do.

Since these sets are in the same field I wonder if I could find multiple points near to each other where the difference between the yield value of one data set to another set is the same to serve as a reference and make a correction factor from there.

The other option would be to divide the points into 5 yield categories and correlate each category.

I have no idea where to start.

Where do you suggest for me to start? Would I get trustful results?

Points of both harvester in the field segregated by color
[image: The points across the field, green points are harvester 1, red harvester 2]

Yield of first harvester across time
[image]

Yield of second harvester across time
[image]

Comment: The data come from different harvesters, at different dates, in different areas? Nothing overlaps? Do you maybe have data from a different season that was collected by one harvester that ran some in the green and red areas? If there is no way to relate a harvester to another by harvests in a common area or something along those lines, this sounds pretty hard to solve.

Comment: The area and the dates overlaps for this set of points, both harvesters operated in the same days (maybe with a day or two of difference). The green and the red areas are the points that each harvester generated during operation

Comment: The areas may be contiguous, but it’s unclear if there is actual overlap. In other words, are there any locations that have red AND green points on them? If not, then they don’t overlap.

Comment: Harvester 2 seems to have 2 "base levels" - one close to harvester 1 levels and one about half as much. Try dividing both data sets by their medians and producing a combined spatial plot with both coded to the same categories. It might help you identify where the high areas in harvester 2 are, and perhaps that might give you a reason. Also you could look at the adjacent rows between the 2 harvesters to see if they co-vary (there are at least 10 sets and perhaps several hundred points to assist). Not perfect but not hard to do and just might help.